# ValueError: Cannot set verify_mode to CERT_NONE when check_hostname is enabled

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to access url mentioned in the code through python, when I set `verify=False` I am getting error `"ValueError: Cannot set verify_mode to CERT_NONE when check_hostname is enabled."`.

When I set `verify=True` I am getting `Max retries exceeded with url: /api/search/users?employeesOnly=true&pid=g453942*&surname=y*&name=x* (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(9, '[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:4044)')))`

But same url I can access through browser without any issue (`I have imported my certificate`).

`Any Idea why this is happening, I have absolutely no clue.`

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

import requests
import os
from OpenSSL import crypto

@app.route("/abc")
def home():
    url = 'https://myurl.com/api/search/users?employeesOnly=true&pid=g453942*&surname=y*&name=x*'
    pkcs12_filename = r"C:\Users\user16\Downloads\certificate_TEST2.p12"
    pkcs12_password = 'pass123'

    p12 = crypto.load_pkcs12(open(pkcs12_filename, 'rb').read(), pkcs12_password.encode())

    # PEM formatted private key
    k = crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_privatekey())

    key_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "myKey.key")
    cert_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "myCert.crt")
    fkey = open(key_path, 'wb')
    fkey.write(k)
    fkey.close()

    # PEM formatted certificate
    c = crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_certificate())
    fcert = open(cert_path, 'wb')
    fcert.write(c)
    fcert.close()

    result = requests.get(url, verify=False, cert=(key_path, cert_path))


    return result


app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

When the file is in local, why not use lunix command to extract key and crt,
then use the below code

```
> import json
import requests
    
clientCrt = "cc.crt"
clientKey = "ck.key"
url = "https://example.com/api"
payload = { "someId": "myID" }
certServer = 'cs.crt'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), verify=certServer, 
                  headers=headers, cert=(clientCrt, clientKey))
print(r.status_code)
print(r.json())
```